# I am trying to make image generator using Unsplash API. The code is giving error "Could'nt find photo". Where is the error?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, api, express

I am trying to render photo in ejs from Unsplash API but the error i am getting is "Couldn't find photo". Kindly let me know the error. I am beginner in coding.
This is my code

```
  <%- include('header'); -%>
<h1>My photo</h1>
<img src='<%= image %>' />

  <%- include('footer'); -%>
```

The major problem i think is with the photo id. I do not know how to add dynamic photo id. Kindly let me know if there other errors also.

```
import express from 'express'
import { createApi } from 'unsplash-js';
import nodeFetch from 'node-fetch';
import https from 'https';
import ejs from 'ejs';
// import unsplash from 'unsplash';
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
const unsplash = createApi({
  accessKey: 'jSkL3CYPolL5G2mk8k28YJa8ITOcobvtWWP_2lRT_Z0',
  fetch: nodeFetch,
});
// const yOUR_ACCESS_KEY = unsplash.accessKey;
const url = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=jSkL3CYPolL5G2mk8k28YJa8ITOcobvtWWP_2lRT_Z0"
// URL = require('url').URL;
// import URL from 'url';

unsplash.photos.get({ photoId: 'pXhwzz1JtQU' }).then(result => {
  if (result.errors) {
    // handle error here
    console.log('error occurred: ', result.errors[0]);
  } else {
    // handle success here
    const photo = result.response;
    console.log(photo);
    app.get("/", function(req, res){

      res.render("home", {image: photo});

    });

  }
});

unsplash.photos.getRandom({});
unsplash.photos.getRandom({
  count: 10,
});
unsplash.photos.getRandom({
  collectionIds: ['abc123'],
  topicIds: ['def456'],
  featured: true,
  username: 'naoufal',
  query: 'dog',
  count: 1,
});

  // throw 'myException'; // generates an exception
  app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on port 3000");
  });
```

Comment: add a catch method to your promise, then specify where the error is coming from. because "Couldn't find photo" seems like a message more than an error. It looks like you couldn't retrieve a photo

Comment: Made some edits to the question

Comment: 1st thing, the Id that you are using is invalid. 
https://api.unsplash.com/photos/pXhwzz1JtQU?client_id=jSkL3CYPolL5G2mk8k28YJa8ITOcobvtWWP_2lRT_Z0
If you put this in your browser, you can see that it also returns a not found response. Be aware this is not an error, this is a result of your query. 

If you try this https://api.unsplash.com/photos/aIBF1XLvwSU?client_id=jSkL3CYPolL5G2mk8k28YJa8ITOcobvtWWP_2lRT_Z0
you can see that it returns a json response. so you call res.render method which will render nothing although your intention is to show an image

Comment: I see that you are using app.get inside your photo fetch operation but it is wrong place and wrong thing to use.
I recommend you to follow a basic express tutorial to see how app.method() is being used. When you are comfortable, split your operations